# Fourier Transform of $\exp{(A\sin(x))}$

Tags: fourier-transform

I would like to know how to calculate the Fourier transform of

$$e^{A\sin(x)}$$

where $A$ is a real positive constant.

Comment: I dont think that it has a trivial expression. You could use a Taylor expansion and then express the solution as a power series.

Comment: Are you sure you mean the Fourier transform and not the Fourier series? It's a periodic function; the Fourier transform will consist of delta pulses.

Comment: @joriki yes I would need the fourier transform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Fourier **series** of $e^{A\sin x}$ is given by:

$$ e^{A\sin x}= I_0(A) + 2\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n I_{2n+1}(A)\sin((2n+1) x)+2\sum_{n\geq 1}(-1)^n I_{2n}(A)\cos(2nx) $$
where $I_n$ is a [modified Bessel function of the first kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html).
 Now you may recover the Fourier transform from the Fourier series.

Comment: Dear Jack, I have recently started learning about Fourier transforms (discrete for now), and am struggling a bit at the moment. If you find the time, your input on any of these questions ([1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3420126/306321), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3420421/306321)) would be most valuable. Many thanks in advance, and I hope you don't mind me contacting you here.