# Series involving modified Bessel functions and sine/cosine functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, bessel-functions

I would like to understand if the following two infinite series can be further expressed in terms of known functions:

$$\sum_{n\geq 0} (-1)^nI_{2n+1}(A)\frac{\cos((2n+1)B)}{2n+1}$$

and

$$\sum_{n\geq 1} (-1)^nI_{2n}(A)\frac{\sin(2nB)}{2n}$$

where $A$ is a positive real constant and $B$ is real. $I_n(\cdot)$ is the nth order of the modified Bessel function of first kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1839071/fourier-transform-of-expa-sinx/1839402#1839402). We have that:

$$ e^{A\sin x}= I_0(A) + 2\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n I_{2n+1}(A)\sin((2n+1) x)+2\sum_{n\geq 1}(-1)^n I_{2n}(A)\cos(2nx) $$
hence by considering the even part and replacing $x$ with $Bx$ we get:
$$ \cosh(A\sin(Bx))= I_0(A) + 2\sum_{n\geq 1}(-1)^n I_{2n}(A)\cos(2nBx) $$
and:
$$ I_0(A)+2\sum_{n\geq 1}(-1)^{n}I_{2n}(A)\frac{\sin(2nB)}{2nB}=\int_{0}^{1}\cosh(A\sin(Bx))\,dx $$
so, by rearranging,
$$\sum_{n\geq 1}(-1)^n I_{2n}(A)\frac{\sin(2nB)}{2n}=\color{red}{-\frac{B}{2} I_0(A)+\frac{B}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\cosh(A\sin(Bx))\,dx} $$
and the other series can be managed in a similar way. From:

$$ \sinh(A\sin(Bx))= 2\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n I_{2n+1}(A)\sin((2n+1)Bx) $$
it follows that:
$$ \color{red}{\frac{B}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\sinh(A\sin(Bx))\,dx} = \sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n I_{2n+1}(A)\frac{1-\cos((2n+1)B)}{2n+1}.$$

Comment: Ok, there is then no closed formula for the series. Thanks anyway

Comment: Could you also explain how to manage the other series? By integrating from 0 to 1 I obtain the extra series $\sum_{n\geq0}(-1)^n\frac{I_{2n+1}(A)}{B(2n+1)}$. Is it equal to some known function?

Comment: @JFNJr: by integrating over $(0,1)$ which function? I got $\frac{\sin(2nB)}{2nB}$ exactly by integrating $\cos(2nB x)$ (with respect to $x$) on the $(0,1)$ interval.

Comment: I refer to the other series I want to express. Could you please write down the steps also for that?

Comment: @JFNJr: they are pretty much the same, you just have to take the odd part. Anyway, updating.

Comment: Are you sure about the factor 2 in front of hyperbolic functions? And also I think there is a typo in the last equation, it should be $n\geq0$.

Comment: @JFNJr: there is something to fix, you are right. But in this case I do not think I will carry on updates, since I already spent some time on this answer and got absolutely nothing from it.

Comment: @JFNJr: thank you. Typos fixed.